# upgrade to nhibernate 3.1

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a project using NHibernate (version 2.2). For upgrade to NHibernate 3.2 , What should I do?

Do I need that upgrade following dlls?

1. NHibernate.Linq.dll
2. Iesi.Collections.dll
3. Castle.Core.dll
4. Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll
5. Log4net.dll

Do I need that upgrade hbm files? Do I need that upgrade hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: You don't need NHibernate.Linq anymore, but you will need to update all your queries since NHibernate has it's own LINQ provider now which falls under 'Query' rather than 'Linq'. You should branch your application and do the upgrade in there because, no doubt you will need to fix your queries and mappings, a lot has changed in 3.0 from 2.1.

Comment: Also you should go accept some answers to your questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When upgrading to NH 3.2 you don't need NHibernate.Linq.dll anymore, **but** method name that is used to get LINQ support is not `Linq<T>` - its `Query<T>` now
2. You don't need to change hbm files
3. You will need to update Iesi.Collections assembly
4. You don't need castle.dynamic proxy dll (you still can use it, but its not required anymore)
5. Log4Net is [not required anymore](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/using-nlog-via-common-logging-with-nhibernate.aspx)
6. You will probably need to change your cfg file in order to [change dynamic proxy settings](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2586)

The easiest way to get latest version of NH with all required assemblies is to use [Nuget](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I done it. 
It has error. 
Because Nhibernate.linq.dll is not match by Nhibernate.dll (ver 3.1)

Message of error is :

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have to upgrade Nh ver 3.1 , What do I need to version of Nhibernate.linq.dll ?

Comment: Either remove NHibernate.Linq assembly, or put assembly redirect

Comment: I done it again. However it has error.  Possible that where there is that i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade the dlls and test your program, normally this should be enough

Comment: LINQ providers are not 100% compatible.