# Upgrade to NHibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a project by NHibernate (version 2.1). For upgrade to NHibernate 3.2, what should I do?

Do I need that upgrade following dll?

1. Antlr3.Runtime
2. Castle.Core
3. Castle.DynamicProxy2
4. NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

I could not find those dll in NHibernate 3.2. Now what should I do?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062243/upgrade-to-nhibernate-3-1/7062577

Answer (score 3):

They are not needed any more. Just delete all dlls that are not there any more (except maybe log4net, that's now optional but without it there won't be any logging).

You might also get errors in your hibernate.cfg.xml, just remove the deleted elements like ProxyFactoryFactory.

Comment: Build failed.Flowing error is given "The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'Castle' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"