# nhibernate upgrade from v2.0 to v4.1

Tags: nhibernate

We want to upgrade a rather large and old project from Nhiberate v2.0 to v4.1 to increase the performance further. Does anybody have any useful tips, howto's or best practices? Another option would be to switch to the Entity Framework if that is easier. Any guesses how many days the upgrade would take?

Comment: Given that NH is mostly stagnant and doesn't offer asynchronous operations, the question should be when to start the migration to EF, not if. Asynchronous operations offer huge benefits to web applications, because they allow them to use fewer threads/CPU while waiting for database responses.

Comment: We develop a Windows application, is EF also superior in this case?

Comment: Even more. If your application blocks waiting for the database, the end user will notice the lag immediatelly

Answer (score 0):

As for the upgrade itself, it should work out of the box, and, yes, you should upgrade it because there are lots of improvements and new features.

As for switching to Entity Framework, lots of things are so different. I suspect that you were not using LINQ with NHibernate 2.0; in Entity Framework, you need to use LINQ. Plus, the mappings are done in a totally different way, using attributes and code in Entity Framework.

Comment: I was not sure if it would work out of the box because of other posts (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062243/upgrade-to-nhibernate-3-1). So we just have to exchange the references?

Comment: Well, were you using LINQ? If so, the method name should now be Query instead of Linq (if I recall correctly). If you only used Criteria API or HQL, it should be the same. Mappings are backwards compatible, although there may be something new.

Comment: Another change is the IEsi Collections: NH 4 now uses the ISet<T> interface from .NET, it no longer needs IEsi.

Comment: We were not using LINQ and no IEsi Collections. We have some trouble with certain methods but that my be caused be previous developers who have overwritten the nhibernate source code.

Comment: Why don't you send an email to the NHibernate Users mailing list? It's available at Google Groups (nhusers).